# EclipseLink uses incorrect table name in queries for subclasses if inheritance type is SingleTable

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, single-table-inheritance

I have three entities using JPA/EclipseLink:

```
@Entity(name = "Sharing")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class AbstractSharingEntity extends AbstractEntity {

@Entity(name = "InternalSharing")
public class InternalSharingEntity extends AbstractSharingEntity {

@Entity(name = "ExternalSharing")
public class ExternalSharingEntity extends AbstractSharingEntity {
```

If I create a typed query for AbstractSharingEntity ("... FROM Sharing ..."), EclipseLink creates the correct query using the specified entity name.

But if I create a typed query for one of the two subclasses (e. g. "... FROM InternalSharing ..."), EclipseLink creates a wrong query using the class name as table name instead of using the entity name. This results in the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'db.ABSTRACTSHARINGENTITY' doesn't exist
```

Did I make any mistake and this is the expected behaviour? How can I create valid queries for the subclasses without changing the class names/removing different entity names?

Comment: Turn on logging and see what EclipseLink says when it processes your persistence unit.

Answer (score 0):

Your expectations are correct IMHO. The default table name is "*entityName*" when no table name is specified, and since you overrode the entity name of the "Abstract" class then the table used should be `SHARING`. And since it has that inheritance then should use that for the subclasses too.

All of those queries should be generating a query of the form

```
"SELECT ... FROM SHARING ..."
```

Raise a bug on your JPA provider.

NOTE: This assumes that `AbstractEntity` is **not** a JPA entity.

You would, of course, require a discriminator on that model, and also your "Abstract" class likely ought to be `abstract`